# Where to place a config file?

Tags: java, plugins, config, ini

Creating a plugin project and I am required to have a config.ini file for the user to enter database connections / DB name etc... Just wondering if there was an industry standard on where to put this file? or is it just personal preference?

I have seen a few different people mention C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local and C:\Program Files\Common Files and couple of different options. is there any other places that could or should have a .ini file as standard.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the location should be /src/main/resources/ in your java project location.. 
that is industry standard as far i am aware of. 
for ini files which needs to be changed for any db information is should in the installed application folder.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I believe it has to be external from the project in order for the user/customer to be able to edit it and insert their DB details etc. If i put it inside of the project it would be packaged with the .jar file and it wont be able to be edited? Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: aah then it should be in the installed folder of the application.. like if u have db2 client installed, the ini file will be in C:/prog/IBM/Db2/...

Comment: So what you are saying is that it should be on the same level hierarchy as the .Jar? So in the same folder essentially. is that right?   This is a plugin is for eclipse and if i am correct my packaged jar will be located inside of the eclipse/plugins folder to extend eclipse which i dont think is a good place for a .ini as it would get lost within the hundreds of other plugins that eclipse includes.

Comment: that was for the installed application level.. now this is for plugin so it should be in the plugins folder only.. the easiest way to find it - check a plugin added to ecipse and locate its ini file.. i am sure it will be in the same plugin folder... if you keep it out somewhere it may be lost.. or deleted by system clean up.